# WCF how to propagate DiagnosticSource.Activity context in WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, open-telemetry

I try to integrate OpenTelemetry with a console exporter in an application that uses WCF.
The problem is, that the trace id of  my current [`System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.Activity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.activity?view=netcore-3.1) is not propagated to the other side.
And thus on the other side the parent information is missing and the trace is broken.

I **did turn on** ActivityPropagation in WCF which is working when examining the logs.

The problem is, that my Activity on the other side has no/wrong Activity Id.

At the moment I am clueless what I can do to also propagate the  `System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.Activity.Id` over WCF

- How do I set up OpenTelemetry or WCF correctly to propagate the Activity Id/Context?

---

The code is basically only the microsoft [WCF Calculator Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/getting-started-tutorial).
Into which I try to integrate OpenTelemetry.

These are the parts where I am using to OpenTelemetry

Client:

```
public class Program
{
    private static readonly ActivitySource MyActivitySource = new ActivitySource("MyCompany.MyProduct.MyClient");

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var tracerProvider = Sdk.CreateTracerProviderBuilder()
            .AddSource("MyCompany.MyProduct.MyClient")
            .AddConsoleExporter()
            .Build();

        using (var activity_wcf_session = MyActivitySource.StartActivity("WCF_Session"))
        {
            activity_wcf_session?.SetTag("index", 0);

            //Step 1: Create an instance of the WCF proxy.
            CalculatorClient client = new CalculatorClient();

            // Step 2: Call the service operations.
            // Call the Add service operation.
            using (var activity = MyActivitySource.StartActivity("Client_call_add()"))
            {
                activity?.SetTag("msg", "foo");
                double result = client.Add(100.00D, 15.99D);
            }
            
            // Step 3: Close the client to gracefully close the connection and clean up resources.
            Console.WriteLine("\nPress <Enter> to terminate the wcf client.");
            Console.ReadLine();
            client.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Service:

```
public class CalculatorService : ICalculator
    {
        private static readonly ActivitySource MyActivitySource = new ActivitySource(
            "MyCompany.MyProduct.CalculatorService");

        private TracerProvider tracerProvider;

        public CalculatorService()
        {
            tracerProvider = Sdk.CreateTracerProviderBuilder()
            .AddSource("MyCompany.MyProduct.CalculatorService")
            .AddConsoleExporter()
            .Build();
        }


        public double Add(double n1, double n2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Activity.Current is null: " + (Activity.Current == null)); // is always null

            using (var activity = MyActivitySource.StartActivity("CalculatorService_add()", ActivityKind.Server))
            {
                // activity.parent is not set

                double result = n1 + n2;
                return result;
            }
        }
        
        // ...
    }
}
```

This is how I activated Activity-Propagation in the projects (same for host)

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information,ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add initializeData="C:\logs\GettingStarted_Client.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" name="xml" />
    </sharedListeners>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
  </system.diagnostics>
```

Comment: For how to properly set up OpenTelemetry, you can refer to this link: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/improvements-in-net-core-3-0-for-troubleshooting-and-monitoring-distributed-apps/

Comment: @DingPeng Thank you for your reply.

I'm not sure if this applies to me, as I am using WCF without an ASP.net Core application. 

But I will try out what is described in there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the HTTP headers and create the `Activity` on your own. Here's how you could do it:

(Requirement: **System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource** nuget package.)

1. Create the following helper classes:

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;

internal sealed class TracingEndpointBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
{
    private readonly TracingMessageInspector messageInspector = new TracingMessageInspector();

    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
        // No-op
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
        // No-op
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
    {
        endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(messageInspector);
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
        // No-op
    }
}

internal sealed class TracingMessageInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
{
    private readonly ActivitySource activitySource = new ActivitySource(nameof(TracingMessageInspector));

    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        return StartActivity(WebOperationContext.Current?.IncomingRequest?.Headers);
    }

    private Activity StartActivity(WebHeaderCollection headers)
    {
        if (headers == null)
        {
            return activitySource.StartActivity("<UnknownAction>", ActivityKind.Server);
        }

        Activity activity = activitySource.StartActivity(
            name: headers[HeaderNames.SOAPAction] ?? "<UnknownAction>",
            kind: ActivityKind.Server,
            parentId: headers[HeaderNames.TraceParent]);

        if (activity == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        activity.TraceStateString = headers[HeaderNames.TraceState];

        string baggageString = headers[HeaderNames.Baggage] ?? headers[HeaderNames.CorrelationContext];
        if (baggageString != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in baggageString.Split(','))
            {
                if (NameValueHeaderValue.TryParse(item, out NameValueHeaderValue baggageItem))
                {
                    activity.AddBaggage(baggageItem.Name, WebUtility.UrlDecode(baggageItem.Value));
                }
            }
        }

        return activity;
    }

    public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        if (correlationState is Activity activity)
        {
            activity.Stop();
        }
    }
}

internal static class HeaderNames
{
    public const string SOAPAction = "SOAPAction";
    public const string TraceParent = "traceparent";
    public const string TraceState = "tracestate";
    public const string CorrelationContext = "Correlation-Context";
    public const string Baggage = "baggage";
}
```

2. At startup, hook up the behavior:

```cs
ServiceHost host = ...;
ServiceEndpoint endpoint = host.AddServiceEndpoint(...);
endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new TracingEndpointBehavior());
```

3. Make sure that there are `ActivityListener`s, otherwise the `Activity`s created by `ActivitySource`s are going to be null. For example:

```cs
ActivitySource.AddActivityListener(new ActivityListener
{
    ActivityStarted = a => Console.WriteLine($"[{DateTime.UtcNow:o}] Started: {a.OperationName} ({a.Id})"),
    ActivityStopped = a => Console.WriteLine($"[{DateTime.UtcNow:o}] Stopped: {a.OperationName} ({a.Id}) took {a.Duration}"),
    ShouldListenTo = _ => true,
    Sample = (ref ActivityCreationOptions<ActivityContext> o) => ActivitySamplingResult.AllDataAndRecorded,
});
```

### Variations

- The code above used `IEndpointBehavior`, but `IServiceBehavior` and `IContractBehavior` would also have worked.
- I chose `headers[HeaderNames.SOAPAction]` for the activity name, but it could have been anything.
- I hooked up the behavior through code, but it's also possible to do it through **app.config** or **web.config** instead. You need to create a `BehaviorExtensionElement` though.

### Notes

- Do not use `IParameterInspector`, because `AfterCall()` is not executed in case of failure.
- I have never used OpenTelemetry SDK, so I don't know if anything above would be different with it.
- Inspiration: https://github.com/jbogard/NServiceBus.Extensions.Diagnostics/blob/b7ef20b5f579809c5ed69ac7518c9d1ddae89884/src/NServiceBus.Extensions.Diagnostics/IncomingPhysicalMessageDiagnostics.cs
- I think WCF activities are different from `System.Diagnostics.Acitivity`s.